base_profile not creating/migrating to SQLite
I am able to migrate base_post to the database but for some reason I do not get any errors relating to base_profile but it is not a table in the database.
migration filemodels.pyviews.pydatabase
I tried to makemigrate, migrate, migrate base zero(which gives me the error of no base_profile as well so it wont delete all the migration files).

Try to make reset to your migration :

Remove the all migrations files within your project
Go through each of your projects apps migration folder and remove everything inside, except the init.py file.

Or if you are using a unix-like OS you can run the following script (inside your project dir):
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete


Drop the current database, or delete the db.sqlite3 if it is your case.

Create the initial migrations and generate the database schema:
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate


see this resource it talk about that : click here

Try to add app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings file in your project
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'appname',

    ]


"INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'base',
]" Sadly I got that already.

Try to make reset to your migration
I make other answer to you to display how you can make reset migration
